# Inserting image to a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I'm trying to save picture in a MySQL database using blob type. When I am uploading it directly from phpMyAdmin it works fine. But in my php code it is not working. The mysqli_error method returns

> Invalid utf8 character string: '\x89PNG'

notice : after connecting to my database I use the code :

```
mysqli_set_charset($Inventory_db, 'utf-8');
mysqli_query($Inventory_db,"set names 'utf8'");
```

And when I remove it or insert a jpg image, it also tells me a terrible error !

Here is the other error :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '????\0JFIF\0,,\0\0??\0tExif\0\0MM\0*\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0J\0\0\0' at line 1

What should I do?

Comment: post your table structure with data type

Comment: please post the code where you retrieve the image and execute the `INSERT` statement. Otherwise you can find tutorials https://blogs.oracle.com/oswald/phps-mysqli-extension:-storing-and-retrieving-blobs

Comment: Personally, I never store images within the database: I save them somewhere on the server and I store in the database their path. This way, the database remains lighter. When then I need to use that image, retrieving its path from the database is quick and easy.

Comment: ah sorry .. I just have a number of a bill with a column that represent the image , whose data type is BLOB.. 
the problem was solved by "mysqli_real_escape_string" ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You *may* be able to use the `LOAD_FILE()` function.  See the restrictions in the manual at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file

```
INSERT INTO ... (..., blob_col, ...)
    VALUES
    (..., LOAD_FILE('/path/to/file'), ...);
```

(As @Marco suggests...)  For web sites, it is normal to leave the file on disk somewhere, then let `<img src=...>` fetch it while the page is being rendered.

Otherwise, Base64 is probably the best bet.  It does enlarge the footprint by 8/6.

The hassles of escaping 8-bit codes to construct a string for inserting into a `BLOB` are daunting.

The utf8 stuff in the Question is irrelevant.  Images *must* be stored in a `BLOB`, not `TEXT` (unless you have encoded it base64 or something else).